# How do we do select query using phantom driver without table defintion

Tags: scala, datastax, datastax-enterprise, phantom-dsl

I have streaming of data coming from SparkStreaming. Which i need to process and finally want to store the data in Cassandra. So, earlier i was trying to use SparkCassandra connector. But it doesn't give the access of SparkStreaming Context object on workers. So, I have to use separate cassandra-scala driver. Hence, i ended up with [phantom](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom). Now, my question is i have already defined the column family in the cassnandra. So, how do i do the select and update query from scala.

I have followed these documentation [link1](http://outworkers.com/blog/post/phantom-tips-3-understanding-phantom-connectors) but i don't understand why do we need to give the table definition at client (scala code) side. Why can't we just give `Keyspace`, `ClusterPoints` and `ColumnFamily` and be done with it.

```
     object CustomConnector {
       val hosts = Seq("IP1", "IP2")
       val Connector = ContactPoints(hosts).keySpace("KEYSPACE_NAME")
    }

      realTimeAgg.foreachRDD{ x => if (x.toLocalIterator.nonEmpty) {
                                x.foreachPartition {
                         How to achieve select/insert in Cassandra table here using phantom
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet possible using phantom, we are actively working on `phantom-spark` to allow you to do this, but at this stage in time this is still a few months away.

In the interim, you will have to rely on the spark cassandra connector and use the non type-safe API to achieve this. It's a more unfortunate setup, but in the very near future this will be resolved.

Comment: Is it possible, If i create the table definition and do the mapping in scala, then can i do the insertion through spark-workers to `cassandra` columnfamily ?